# XAML syntax (machine-readable)

Tags: wpf, xaml, syntax, xsd, visualization

Is there a formal definition of the XAML syntax? There is a PDF document describing XAML in terms of XML Infoset but I haven't been able to find a mechanic description (XSD, RelaxNG or similar). Basically I want to take the schema and create a visualization of the syntax (new to XAML).

XAML goes beyond WPF of course but I'm mostly interested in XAML for WPF development and want a visual schema to get an overview over how constructs can be combined.

Comment: A better way to learn it might be by knowing XML and the classes that you are going to use (WPF, Silverlight, WF, WP, ...) and general XAML constructions (`<Control.Property>`)from the x: namespace (extensions etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is not possible to use XSD to fully describe a schema for XAML due to it's extensible nature.

However, saying that, there are some .xsd files which are an attempt to provide a close approximation.

Have a look in a directory of Visual Studio:

```
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Xml\Schemas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas
```

for `wpfe.xsd` and `xaml2006.xsd`.

(you might also see references to `xaml.xsd` and `xaml2005.xsd` on the web....provided through older sources).

The early versions of Visual Studio/XAML (e.g. Visual Studio 2005 with the WinFX addon) used to use those xsd's to provide basic intellisense support. Nowadays I they use a different technique (a Language Service) to provide the intellisense support for XAML.

- http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2008/04/25/xaml-editing-in-slickedit.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/12/10/42513.aspx